# CMake: Can't link to targets within same project

Tags: c++, cmake, linker-errors

I am attempting to link library2 to library1, both of which are in the same source tree:

```
MyProject
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Library1
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── include
│       └── foo.h
│       └── bar.h
│   └── src
│       └── foo.cpp
│       └── bar.cpp
├── Library2
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── include
│       └── baz.h
│   └── src
│       └── baz.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17.0)
project(MyProject)

option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ON)

add_subdirectory(Library1)
add_subdirectory(Library2)
```

Library1/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Library1)

add_library(library1 
    src/foo.cpp 
    src/bar.cpp
)

target_include_directories(library1 PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1/include
)
```

Library2/CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Library2)

add_library(library2 
    src/baz.cpp
)

target_include_directories(library2 PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library1/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Library2/include
)

target_link_libraries(library2 PUBLIC library1)
```

But when library2 gets to it's linking stage, I get this error:

```
usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibrary1
```

It seems the linker is not looking in the source tree for `library1`. I have tried adding the path to the target directly though `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` and through `link_directories()` (also tried `target_link_directories()`). I also cannot use `find_library()` as `library1` doesn't exist until it is actually built by running `make`.

How do I link to a target that will be generated as part of the same project? I feel like this should work.

Comment: Is this the exact code producing the error? Are you sure you don't have a typo in your target names?

Comment: Projects are independent namespaces. Drop the `project` line on the two libraries.